# Getting where user is coming from: request.referer not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers, rails-routing

When a user goes to a page while not logged in, they get redirected back to my login page.

```
def authenticate_user!
  redirect_to new_user_path unless current_user
end
```

Then in my Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    puts request.referer          #=> nil
    puts request.referrer         #=> nil
    puts request["HTTP_REFERER"]  #=> nil
    puts request["HTTP_REFERRER"] #=> nil
    ...
  end
end
```

I don't get anything from the `referrer` variables when going to another page (but it redirects to `/users/new` correctly).  Even when directly navigating to the `/users/new` page I get nothing for any of those variables. How do I get the path they came from? I've seen examples using the below code, but `referrer` should not be nil

```
previous = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.referer)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `I don't get anything when going to another page (it redirects it correctly)`?

Comment: Sorry I'll update the question to be more clear, but I was referring to the before filter redirecting correctly, but not filling out the request referrer header